# Error in plot(qs, props) : unused argument (props)

Tags: r

I was trying to run the code, but some errors jumped out. I don't know how to fix it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

data("gapminder")
View(gapminder)

x <- filter(gapminder, year == "1952") %>% select(lifeExp) %>% unlist
```

I want to plot the proportions of countries with life expectancy q for a range of different years.

```
prop = function(q){
  mean(x <=q)
}
qs = seq(from=min(x), to=max(x), length=20)
props = sapply(qs, prop)
plot(qs, props)
```

> Error in plot(qs, props) : unused argument (props)

**I used View(props), it has data inside, so what does "unused argument" mean?**

```
plot(ecdf(x))
```

> Error in i:i : NA/NaN argument

Comment: Hi, I've run your code and it works as expected, providing both plots with no errors. Can you try restarting your R session and running just the code in your question again?

Comment: Works for me too. Have you defined your own `plot` function perhaps?

Comment: @AllanCameron, after I restart my R session, it works now. Thank you.

Comment: @Edward, after I restart my R session, the code works. Thank you.